How to deal with vectors that are orthogonal to cointegration vectors?
In the context of cointegration, when we have the long-term equilibrium defined as $\mathbf{\beta}\mathbf{p} = \eta$, introducing an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{v}$ that is orthogonal to $\beta$ doesn't alter this equilibrium condition as the equilibrium remains expressed as $\beta(\mathbf{p+v})=\eta$. However, if I am using cointegration to do predictions or other similar usages, how should I know whether $\mathbf{p}$ or $\mathbf{p+v}$ is the correct data point as both of them yield $\eta$ after multiplying $\beta$?
